# Rails with my custom css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy my application on heroku,everything is working fine,except for my custom.css.scss file.

This is my css file,which either not getting uploaded on heroku or may be its not getting rendered properly.

Please help me with this.

Here is my production.rb file

```
MyTodo::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

#config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```

Please help me in deploying my application.

Note i have included these lines in my custom.css.scss file

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Here is my gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
 # sass-rails needs to be higher than 3.2

#gem 'font-awesome-less'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'rake', '~> 10.1.1'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'


  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end


group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'
end


group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  #gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'shelly-dependencies'
   gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Here is my application.css file

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .

*/
```

Comment: Let's see your Gemfile

Comment: I have added my gemfile,so you can check now

Comment: is this a typo "custom.css.scc" ?

Comment: yes i am sorry,that's a typo

Comment: can you show  first 10 lines of applicaiton.css if you edited it?

Comment: I have added my application.css file,you can check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this .....Rails Asset Pipeline on Heroku Cedar

reference link :
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Compiling assets locally

If a public/assets/manifest.yml is detected in your app, Heroku will assume you are handling asset compilation yourself and will not attempt to compile your assets. Rails 4 uses a file called public/assets/manifest-.json instead. On both versions you can generate this file by running $ rake assets:precompile locally and checking the resultant files into Git.

To compile your assets locally, run the assets:precompile task locally on your app. Make sure to use the production environment so that the production version of your assets are generated.

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

A public/assets directory will be created. Inside this directory you’ll find a manifest.yml which includes the md5sums of the compiled assets in Rails 3. In Rails 4 the file will be manifest-.json. Adding public/assets to your git repository will make it available to Heroku.

git add public/assets
git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"

Now when pushing, the output should show that your locally compiled assets were detected:

-----> Preparing Rails asset pipeline
       Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally